# c macro - how to set a macro name as the output of another macro

Tags: c, macros, concatenation

I want to do create a macro whose name is a concatenation of two things i.e.

```
#define name ## _body(a) \
    a
```

but `gcc -E` gives the error

> macros.c:9:18: error: '##' cannot appear at either end of a macro expansion
>    #define typename ## _body(body) \

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to do this *using only C preprocessor*?

Comment: Does a solution that invokes the preprocessor twice count?

Comment: @melpomene this is related to micropython. I doubt they're going to allow a commit which changes the build-system like that.

Comment: No way you can do this.

Comment: Obligatory general advice: don't do stuff like this with CPP macros, unless it's for fun, or for being evil, or because others were evil already and you must suffer the consequences...

Comment: @hyde if it's not possible, that's not relevant. If it is possible, I'd like to know because it will be useful to devs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a macro definition, the name part is always a single preprocessor token. However, you can use function-like macros, with parameters, that expand to a single token.

Consider the following macros:

```
#define  JOIN(a,b)       a ## b

#define  FOO(suffix)     JOIN(FOO_, suffix)
#define  FOOBAZ          JOIN(FOO_, BAZ)
#define  FOOBAAZ         JOIN(foo_, baaz)

#define  FOO_BAR         first
#define  FOO_BAZ         second
```

With the above definitions, declaring

```
int FOO(BAR) = 1;
int FOOBAZ = 2;
int FOOBAAZ = 3;
```

is equivalent to (i.e., gets preprocessed to)

```
int first = 1;
int second = 2;
int foo_baaz = 3;
```

---

There are cases (especially when exploring various algorithms) when templates or polymorphic code is useful. Consider for example the following **ops.h**:

```
#if defined(TYPE) && defined(PREFIX)
#undef   JOIN2
#define  JOIN2_(a,b)  a ## b
#define  JOIN2(a,b)   JOIN2_(a, b)
#define  NAME(end)    JOIN2(PREFIX, end)

static inline TYPE NAME(_add)(const TYPE val1, const TYPE val2)
{
    return val1 + val2;
}

static inline TYPE NAME(_sub)(const TYPE val1, const TYPE val2)
{
    return val1 - val2;
}

static inline TYPE NAME(_neg)(const TYPE val)
{
    return -val;
}

static inline TYPE NAME(_mul)(const TYPE val1, const TYPE val2)
{
    return val1 * val2;
}

static inline TYPE NAME(_div)(const TYPE val1, const TYPE val2)
{
    return val1 / val2;
}

#endif

#undef   NAME
#undef   JOIN2
#undef   PREFIX
#undef   TYPE
```

The macro `NAME(suffix)` expands to a single token consisting of the expansion of `PREFIX` immediately followed by the expansion of `suffix`. (If they are not preprocessor macros, they are used as-is.)  This allows the same header file to be included multiple times, assuming `PREFIX` is defined to a new value each time.

Note that it is common to have a space between e.g. `NAME(_add)` and the following `(const TYPE val1, const TYPE val2)`.  I omitted it, in the hopes that it makes the function definitions more familiar-looking.

Let's look at an example program using such a header file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  TYPE    uint32_t
#define  PREFIX  u32
#include "ops.h"

#define  TYPE    float
#define  PREFIX  float
#include "ops.h"

#define  TYPE    double
#define  PREFIX  dbl
#include "ops.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("dbl_div(217.0, 31.0) = %.1f\n", dbl_div(217.0, 31.0));
    printf("u32_sub(4, 2) = %" PRIu32 "\n", u32_sub(4, 2));
    printf("float_mul(1.25f, 72.00f) = %.2ff\n", float_mul(1.25f, 72.00f));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The first `#include "ops.h"` defines functions `u32_add()`, `u32_sub()`, `u32_neg()`, `u32_mul()`, and `u32_div()`.  The second defines functions `float_add()` and so on, and the third `dbl_add()` and so on.

The above files are valid C99, and when compiled and run, it outputs

```
dbl_div(217.0, 31.0) = 7.0
u32_sub(4, 2) = 2
float_mul(1.25f, 72.00f) = 90.00f
```

If you combine the above with suitable macros using C11 `_Generic`, you can make "functions" that call different implementations based on the type of their argument.

Comment: But this work for macros? Can I create a macro name like this without doing multiple invocations of the preprocessor?

Comment: @Adrian: Read the first line again. **The macro name is always a single token**. You cannot use `#define` to create a macro whose name is anything other than a single token. You cannot paste or join tokens to form the name of the macro to be defined: those only work in the value part.

Comment: K. I didn't understand what that implied.

Comment: @Adrian: Oh, okay. I don't know how to put it clearer than that. The point of my answer is to show that you don't need to do that. You can use function-like macros, that expand to the desired combined value, based on the macro parameters.